# Android - What's the best way to create a Slideshow?

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the best way to create a slideshow in Android?
Basically, what I need is to slide through a collection of LinearLayout or RelativeLayout objects, that contains inside them different views, ex: an ImageView and a TextView overlayed on that image.
On the bottom of the screen, should be some bulled points that will keep track of the currently element in the gallery.

To give an idea take a look at this jQuery implementation: http://slidesjs.com/
(I don't need the "left"/"right" controls, and the bulled points also dont need to be clickable, as in example)

Also, the slideshow should be in a cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best, but I used a `Gallery`.